# Fail 1 : android.os.networkonmainthreadexception

Tags: java, android

```
package com.haviz.androidtosql;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String name;
    String id;
    InputStream is=null;
    String result=null;
    String line=null;
    int code;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText e_id=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final EditText e_name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        Button insert=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                id = e_id.getText().toString();
                name = e_name.getText().toString();
                insert();
            }
        });
    }

    public void insert() {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",id));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",name));

        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.10.0.176:3006/Insert/insert.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                            (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {                                  

            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());

        }   
        try
        {
            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
            code=(json_data.getInt("code"));

            if(code==1) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted Successfully",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }    
    }
```

How do I fix this problem? Please help

**Error Message :**

```
Fail 1 : android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
Fail 2 : java.lang.NullPointerExeption: lock == null
Fail 3 : java.lang.NullPointerExeption
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Don't worry use AsyncTask

Comment: Welcome to the site. Do you have a question?